# postgresql check json field contains

Tags: json, postgresql

I have some json struct, and try check is string contains some value?
I need check, is it words contains 222.

For example:

```
{
    "words": "111, 222"
}
```

Comment: You should at least store that list of values as a JSON array, rather than a comma separated string

Comment: question not about array

Comment: Yes, but it _should_ be. Your example would be better stored as `{ "words": ["111, 222"]}` which makes accessing each element in the list much easier. Storing comma separated values in a single string is always a bad choice to begin with. And that includes JSON as well.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to chack that 222 is available in string or not then try the includes function**

OBJECT_NAME.words.includes("222");   //it gives you true

OBJECT_NAME.words.includes("22222");   //it gives you false

Comment: I think pingWIN wants a SQL/Postgres solution

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LIKE`

```
SELECT ', ' || ('{"words": "111, 222"}'::json->>'words') || ', ' LIKE '%, 222, %';
```

`regexp_split_to_array` and the array contains operator `@>`

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_array('{"words": "111, 222"}'::json->>'words', ', ') @> ARRAY['222'];
```

or `EXISTS` and `regexp_split_to_table()`

```
SELECT EXISTS (SELECT *
                      FROM regexp_split_to_table('{"words": "111, 222"}'::json->>'words', ', ') stt (c)
                      WHERE stt.c = '222');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=e615607b9c5d417fbbb516711eede9a9)